# Why scaleToFill not filling the whole screen?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to use an image as the background of the app.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // ZStack: Background, ScrollView(vertical)
        ZStack {
            Image("background_green").resizable().scaledToFill().opacity(0.8)
                .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            VStack {
                
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        }
        
    }
}
```

How come there are still some white space at the top?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore safe area, like

```
var body: some View {
    
    // ZStack: Background, ScrollView(vertical)
    ZStack {
        Image("background_green").resizable().scaledToFill().opacity(0.8)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)              // << here !!

        VStack {

        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}
```